# Accessing smartcard keystore in an applet, through a js call

Tags: java, applet, smartcard

I am attempting to access the smartcard keystore, by an applet, through a js call.
I am searching for best pratices, and hopefully a guide, minding the security issues.
What I can and cannot do in it?
Just the use of doPrevileged is enough?
What are the limitations that an applet has in those matters?
Should use a JApplet or an Applet?

I really do need some directions.

I just have one request: I don't want to make use of outside libraries.

Thanks

Addendum: 
as It seems, the sun documentation explains that:

> Signed Applets
>
> Signed applets do not have the security restrictions that are imposed
>   on unsigned applets and can run outside the security sandbox.
>
> Note:
>
> **JavaScript code is treated like unsigned code.** When a signed
>   applet is accessed from JavaScript code in an HTML page, the applet is
>   executed within the security sandbox. This implies that the signed
>   applet essentially behaves likes an unsigned applet.

But I have come to other applets that, although their methods are called in js, use JDialog so the user starts the action.

Answer (score 1):

Smartcard is a wide term, you will be fine even with so called **cryptocard** (the difference is smartcard can host applications while cryptocard provides only fixed set of cryptography functions). There is a new serie (looks it will have only two part though) about this topic here: http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2011/09/using-smart-card-as-keystore-in-java.html .

You'll probably find that finding not too expensive and multiplatform solution is not easy.